# Excel VB Copy and Pasting Hyperlinks

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel, hyperlink

I am having trouble copying and pasting the hyperlinks from one sheet to another using VB.

I am using a database connection to pull the hyperlinks into Sheet1 and then using a macro to copy and paste the database data into another sheet, however the copy and pasting doesnt paste the "Clickable" link, only plain text.

How do I go about copying a hyperlink using VB, is this even possible??

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("J19:K100").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
**Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy**
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("C5:D100").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste **Link:=True**
```

Any help is much appreciated! 
Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I am using a database connection, which holds the URL/Hyperlinks. I have tried your code for filtered table, however this only works if the links are directly input into the cell. i.e entered through right click on cell > Hyperlink.

Has anyone achieved copying URL's from a database connection in excel before?

Thanks.

Comment: The size of the copy and paste regions is different. The paste region is a minimum of 14 rows larger than the original copy; more so if the hinted at `xlCellTypeVisible` represents filtered data at the source.

Comment: This seems to work for me
'Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J19:K100").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C5")
'

Comment: @Davesexcel - you need back-ticks  (aka *graves*) to show code formatting, not standard single quotes.

Comment: Okay,
`Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J19:K100").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C5") `

Answer (score 0):

You can use following paste special option to paste links.

```
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```

Comment: This is something that I am looking for however I am getting the following error: "PasteSpecial method of worksheet class failed." All i need to do is copy and paste a filtered database table including the links (if possible without formatting).

Comment: did you try @Davesexcel 's answer above? It seems it will solve your problem. Like Jeeped already said your copy range and paste range is not matching. You can select a single cell (start point) as paste target.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help so far, it doesn't seem to work. I am using that code in excel vba developer but only copies the text (Blue font and underlined) but without the Hyperlink attached. 

EDIT: I am using the database refresh button to refresh the filtered data, it receives the hyperlink from that database and pastes it into the filtered cells. It doesn't copy the address (URL) or the Formula (=Hyperlink[@CHANGE_LINK]...) into the cell .